# Does oracle ODI delete all options in IKM sql incremental update have transaction?

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I am using oracle ODI to sync tables.
I am using IKM SQL Incremental Update,and i set DELETE_ALL to TRUE.
The source data has about 60000+ rows,because it's readonly, i cannot use cdc.
The problem is,when i run this mapping,the target table data will be deleted,when i select,there shows no data.After completed,the data can be seleted.
In my opinion,**i think delete and insert should in same transaction,whenever i select ,there should have data.**
Is my understand right? Or am i using the wrong way?

Comment: Hi Jiang,

You are write will all your suppositions.
But still, it should work like you said.

You should check if is Checked the IKM option named "Commit".

Comment: the option "Commit" is set to defult value "TRUE". So,this means, i cannot use odi to sync this table? When source table delete rows, the target alse need to delete.But "IKM SQL Incremental Update"  can not delete,it can only insert and update.Is my understand right?

Comment: @jiangruixin you might have to customize the IKM Integration Module by changing the `Target Transaction` and `Target Commit` options so that a single commit is performed at the end of the whole task instead of one after each step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aim is to sync a small table. So i shoule use "Control Append" mode.But in this question,i use "Incremental Update" mode,this is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the default order for steps, but oracle made it very easy to customise it. I recommend you to make another copy from the IKM, modify it, give it a suitable name and then use the new copy.